# Determine current month variable that rolls over to next month after the 15th day- python 2.7

Tags: python, datetime

I use the current_month variable to query data but here's the catch-  if the day in the month is later then the 15th, I want to set the current month to be the following month. So the current month for 4/16/2016 should be 5/1/2016.   I've got code that works but it doesn't feel pythonic. Suggestions would be appreciated.

```
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m")
year = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")

#Check if day in the month is past 15th if so set current month 
if int(day) > 15:
    if int(month) < 9: # check if the month in 1-9 if so pad leading zero
        x = int(month)+1
        current_month = year+"-0"+str(x)+"-01"
    if int(month) == 9: # check if the month in 1-9 if so pad leading zero
    x = int(month)+1
        current_month = year+"-"+str(x)+"-01"
    elif int(month) == 12: # check if the month is Dec if so roll to the next year and set month to Jan
    month = "01"
    y = int(year)+1
    current_month = str(y)+"-"+month+"-01"
    else:
        x = int(month)+1 # just add one to the month if months are 10 or 11
    current_month = year+"-"+str(x)+"-01"
else:
     current_month = year+"-"+month+"-01"  #prior to the 15'th so just use normal year, month and day
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add 16 days to the current date and then set the day to be 1?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Adding days might be inaccurate because of different numbers of days in different months.  It would be more accurate to subtract 15 days and then set the day to be 1 and add one month.

Comment: @zondo: Or only do it if the adjustment is needed

Answer (score 2):

```
# Get today's date/time
today = datetime.datetime.now()
# add 16 days if after the 15th
if today.day > 15:
    today += datetime.timedelta(16)
# Format that date w/ day being 1
current_month = today.strftime("%Y-%m-01")
```

Comment: elegant solution! Thank you @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Scott's approach (which works perfectly well and you should probably accept it) is to use a [`dateutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def next_month_after_day(dt, trans_day=15):
    rd = relativedelta(months=(dt.day > trans_day), day=1)

    return dt + rd

dt1 = datetime(1996, 2, 3)
dt2 = datetime(1996, 2, 15)
dt3 = datetime(1996, 2, 16)
dt4 = datetime(1996, 12, 18)

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
for x in (dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4):
    dt_before = x
    dt_after = next_month_after_day(x)
    print('{} -> {}'.format(dt_before.strftime(fmt), dt_after.strftime(fmt)))
```

The result is:

```
1996-02-03 -> 1996-02-01
1996-02-15 -> 1996-02-01
1996-02-16 -> 1996-03-01
1996-12-18 -> 1997-01-01
```

Thanks to Scott for pointing out why my original approach was needlessly complicated (and wrong).

Comment: I thought the day should be 1 no matter what; the question was how to get the correct month.

Comment: @ScottHunter Good call. Fixed.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't test if for December.

Comment: @ScottHunter Ugh. It's easy enough to fix, but I think I'll just delete it instead, since your version is easily much better. Ah well. So much for trying to be explicit about what's going on!

Comment: Actually, I'll just change the method completely. Thanks for the pointer.